# How to retrieve data from cache memory?

Tags: android, caching, video, decode, encode

I'm downloading a video file from vimeo and it is successful but the thing is i need to encode the downloaded video into .txt file and decode from a button to play in my custom video player.

Note: I need to encode the video file from cache memory at the time of downloading.

Comment: Can you define what exactly `"encode video into .txt file"` means?

Comment: i need to convert ".mp4 to .txt (text) file"

Comment: Still does not make any sense. Video to text? You will not retain video, and not likely to have meaningful text.

Comment: oh thanks.. then to which format should i encode to retrieve back to .mp4?? @mvp

Comment: Of course you can convert to text.  Google for Base64.  But, **why** are you trying to do this.  It's sounds very inefficient.  Why not just save it as mp4?

Comment: User should view downloaded video only in my video player.. and not in any other player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to add the extension .txt to the .mp4 file.
i.e `video.mp4.txt`by this the other video player 'll not detect your video.